# How to save the path of my new image to the database as a string so that after creating a new record I can see the image that I selected?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a model Record where I want to save my image path when I pick a photo:

```
public class Record {
...
    public string ImageFile { get; set; }
}
```

I have a RecordEntry.xaml:

```
<Image x:Name="FileImage" 
            Source="{Binding Path=ImageFile, Converter={StaticResource ImageSourceConverter}}"
            WidthRequest="200"
            HeightRequest="200"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" 
            VerticalOptions="Center"/>
<Button Text="Pick Photo"
            BackgroundColor="Teal" 
            TextColor="White" 
            FontSize="40" 
            Clicked="PickPhotoClicked"/>
```

So, I have a RecordEntry.cs where I pick a photo using Plugin.Media:

```
 private async void PickPhotoClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
        if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("No Pick Photo", ":( No Pick Photo available", "OK");
            return;
        }

        _mediaFile = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();
        if (_mediaFile == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        await DisplayAlert("File Path", _mediaFile.Path, "OK");

        FileImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
        {
            return _mediaFile.GetStream();
        });
    }
```

After I selected the photo I want to save the path and bind it to **ImageFile** and I want to see my photo when I open this record again.

Comment: `_mediaFile.Path` contains the path, just use that.  What part of this don't you understand how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Xamarin.Essentials: Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android#using-preferences) to store and read the `File Path`.

**Store the path:**

```
private async void PickPhotoClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //...
    await DisplayAlert("File Path", _mediaFile.Path, "OK");

    //Store your path here
    Preferences.Set("my_File_Path", _mediaFile.Path);

    FileImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
    {
        return _mediaFile.GetStream();
    });
}
```

**Use the path:**, use the `ImageFile` if it exist:

```
public Record _record{ get; set; }

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    _record = new Record();
    string myValue = Preferences.Get("my_File_Path", "default_value");
    _record.ImageFile = myValue;

    BindingContext = _record;
}
```

And in your `ImageSourceConverter`, convert the `imagePath` to `ImageSource`:

```
public class myImageSourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var path = (string)value;
        return ImageSource.FromFile(path);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I uploaded a sample [here](https://github.com/XfHua/Xamarin.Essentials-Preferences) and let me know if you have any questions.